# Pass GridView id to javascript in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am using the below code to handle the gridview dropdownlist on change event in clientside. In the mean time i want to pass the row id for my further process. But it's not working. But it's working while i call javascript without id.How can i pass the id to javascript.

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="10px" HeaderText="Status">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_status" runat="server" onchange='chng_status("<%#Bind("FLD_ID") %>")' >
                                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Realised</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Non-Realised</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>

function chng_status(value) {
        alert('enter');
        alert(value);
    }
```

Comment: what is FLD_ID you are passing this value to function. where are you going to use gridview's ID in which js function..?

Comment: I want to pass fld_id to the javascript funtion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_status" runat="server"
  onchange='<%# Eval("FLD_ID","chng_status(\"{0}\");") %>' >
```

I am using string formatting to pass the value to a javascript function.

Note that i don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve